# Switching from Linux DHCP Server to Windows Server DHCP

Tags: windows-server-2012, linux-networking, dhcp-server

We are using a DHCP server out of a linux OS right now for our subnet.  I am thinking of changing to a Windows DHCP Server, however, because it might be easier for future admins.

What I want to do is to add the DHCP Server role to Windows Server (which I know how to do) and set up the DHCP options.  I need to be able to configure in the options what I have in the linux DHCP options (`tftp-server-name`; `netbios-name-servers`, `ntp-servers`).

My question however, is this: can I set up this DHCP server and test it on just one or two devices without interfering with the DHCP server (on the linux box) that manages my network?  Can I add the role to Windows Server without that taking over DHCP duties on my network until I get it configured?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start a windows DHCP scope with a range of addresses to serve that does not overlap the range served by the Linux host.

So you could install the Windows role, setup a scope that only offers a few addresses.

On your Linux server setup exclusions, or adjust the size of your range if you need to.

Comment: So as long as they are not serving the same ranges it is okay?  I guess I should know that; we have two dhcp servers, one for each of our two subnets (connected over a vpn) and one serves one range, and the other servers the other range.  Thanks for the confirmation!  I'm happy now!